# Trying to save a file as .dat on mac

Tags: java, macos, bluej, textedit

My computer science class (java) requires us to save a series of numbers in an external file which we save to the project folder as a .dat file, and then write a program that accesses it.

The issue is that I have a mac, and I am limited to TextEdit, the files from which I cannot seem to be able to save as.dat files.  (The course is pc based, and everyone else is using notepad)

[Me trying to save the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X49ss.png)

Also...my mac runs on OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TextEdit, create a new file. Set the "Format->Make Plain Text" from menu.

Then do the "File->Save As". Save the file with "UTF-8" for "Plain Text Encoding".